# Comparing values of two keys in a dictionary and saving the highest value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So I'm taking my dictionary key:value pairs from a list and I want to create a dictionary out of it.
They keys are years but each year occurs 12 times, I want the highest value of each year to be stored in my dictionary. This is hottest_day{} which represents the hottest day of that year. I've added an example screenshot of the data as well.

```
import os
file_list = os.listdir('./weatherdata/')

hottest_day = {}
for file_name in file_list:
    max_temp = -99
    with open('weatherdata/' + file_name) as f:
        line = f.read().splitlines()
        req_line = line[2:-1]
        for lines in req_line:
            lines = lines.split(',')
            year = lines[0].split('-')[0]
            try:
                temp = int(lines[1])
            except ValueError:
                continue
            if temp >= max_temp:
                max_temp = temp
            if year in hottest_day:                 
                hottest_day[year] = max_temp
print(hottest_day)
```

This is my code so far, let me know if that is enough context.
I'm getting this right now which is obviously the last key that it has found, I need to compare values and print the key with the highest value.

> {'2007': 43, '2010': 44, '2006': 23, '1997': 41, '2001': 37, '2008': 30, '2003': 28, '1998': 31, '2005': 30, '2009': 31, '2002': 42, '2011': 22, '1999': 21, '2000': 44, '1996': 24, '2004': 41}

part of the input file screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTDcg.png

Comment: Sorry but no, there's not enough context. What do your inputs look like ? Where does `temp` comes from ? IOW, please post a proper MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I took data from a bunch of csv files, which were temperatures by month, put it in a list and took data from it. The year was one column of the file and temp was another. I can post more of the code or data from the files if you like. My first question was closed due to too much context.

Comment: Did you read the page I liinked too ? "MCVE" means "Minimal Complete Verifiable Example".  Your first post obviously failed on the "minimal" criteria, now this one fails on the "complete" and "verifiable".  You have to post at least an example input list (as short as possible but no shorter than needed to reproduce the issue) and the full code acting on it (possibly editing out irrelevant operations).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I've edited it, please see if this solves the problem. Also please be a little kind, I'm new here and new to programming.

Comment: I AM being kind - I kindly asked for the missing parts, linked you to a page explaining what was needed if you expected to get a useful answer, explained the concept of MCVE a second time, all of which took me time that I'm not getting paid for. I could have just voted to close your post and downvoted it without explanations or posted a totally bogus answer based on wild guess.

Comment: Can you include the input and desired output that would make this much easier for us

Answer (score 0):

basically, your main problem is that you want the max temperature per year but you're using a single `max_temp` variable for all years. You need to keep a distinct 'max_temp' for each year. A simple solution here is to use a `defaultdict` for `hottest_day` with your initial `-99` "max_temp" value as default:

```
from collections import defaultdict

hottest_day = defaultdict(lambda: -99)

for file_name in file_list:
    with open('weatherdata/' + file_name) as f:
        # nb: this is a list of lines so it should be a plural
        # nb2: beware, you're reading the whole file in memory,
        # this can crash on huge files.
        lines = f.read().splitlines()

    lines = lines[2:-1]
    for line in lines:
        # nb : python as a `csv` module, which might be safer
        line = line.split(',')
        year = line[0].split('-')[0]
        try:
            temp = int(line[1])
        except ValueError as e:
            # you may want to log the error somewhere
            # for debugging...
            continue
        # defaultdict magic: if `year` has
        # not been set yet, it will default to -99
        if temp >= hottest_day[year]:
            hottest_day[year] = temp
```